# PHP Mail form not sending emails on Linux server

Tags: php, html, css, linux, email

This is my code and my form... it acts like the email was sent, but it never arrives.

I would like to know what could possibly be wrong... Anyone?

The website is hosted on a Linux server, and I don't really know if the server could be blocking the emails because of some kind of incompatibility... I don't really know what it could be.

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die();
} 

$to_Email       = "myemail@gmail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
$subject        = 'Ah!! My email from Somebody out there...'; //Subject line for emails

//check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
{
    die();
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Name is too short or empty!');
    exit();
}
if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Please enter a valid email!');
    exit();
}
if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Only numbers allowed in phone field');
    exit();
}
if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Too short message! Please enter something.');
    exit();
}

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "rn" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

if(!$sentMail)
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Couldnot send mail! Sorry..');
    exit();
}else{
    echo 'Hi '.$user_Name .', Thank you for your email! ';
    echo 'Your email has already arrived in my Inbox, all I need to do is Check it.';
}
 }
?>
```

Here's my form:

```
<fieldset id="contact_form">
<legend>My Contact Form</legend>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="inputt" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />


   <input type="text" name="email" id="inputt" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />


    <input type="text" name="phone" id="inputt" placeholder="Phone Number" />


    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Name"></textarea>


   <button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: What does the maillog on the server say? Most Linux distributions have it under either `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: Sat May 04 05:54:58 2013] [error] [client 189.62.216.81] sendmail: option requires an argument -- r, referer: http://zerodesign.com.br/
[Sat May 04 05:54:58 2013] [error] [client 189.62.216.81] sendmail: option requires an argument -- r, referer: http://zerodesign.com.br/

Answer (score 0):

Your `$headers` are wrong, you're appending `"rn"` instead of `"\r\n"`. Try this instead:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$user_Email. "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_Email. "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Answer (score 0):

According from your comment out of the maillog you need to adjust your php.ini to include the `--r` argument to your `sendmail_path`.

By default it usually is:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Apparently you are using another argument that also requires the --r argument. Appending that to your sendmail_path should get a long way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that, could you explain it, please?

Comment: I've found the php.ini on the ftp, what do I do now?

Comment: All the global PHP settings are saved in a file called `php.ini`, usually located in the `/etc` folder of your Linux installation. In there, the above line should be set, but most likely with other arguments. Check what it's set to and what could be requiring the -r flag. See http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sendmai.htm for a complete list of arguments.